# 'ServiceProcess' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to create a web service to send commands to a windows service: stop, start ...etc.
I added the reference to the System.ServiceProcess and compiles with no errors, but when run the service it gives me this error.

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceProcess' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Add Referece in the solution explorer  `System.ServiceProcess.dll`

the on the using directive `using System.ServiceProcess;`